# Какая версия python на данный момент актуальна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

После перехода на python 3.8 вне зависимости от того, в какую директорию он установлен (на диск 'C:' или диск 'D:') и какие параметры стоят в path, pip стал некорректно работать, постоянно слетает и библиотеки работают некорректно. Много ли я потеряю вернувшись обратно на python 3.7? Там на протяжении всего времени проблем с pip-ом и библиотеками не было. 
Обновляются ли библиотеки на python 3.7 версии?

Comment: Актуальны 3.6 и новее

Comment: Ответ очень прост - проверьте новые «фичи», которые появились в Python 3.8 и ответьте себе на вопрос - можете ли вы жить без этих новых фич 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Главная фишка python 3.8 это присваивание внутри условия:

```
if (n := len(a)) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

Можно пока без этого жить. Основная масса библиотек пока поддерживают python 3.5+. Думаю пока не страшно оставаться на 3.7, но обновляйтесь на минорные релизы на боевых машинах. Сейчас актуальна версия 3.7.7

Comment: А внутри лямбд это присваивание тоже работает? :)

Comment: работает, но не до конца.)

Comment: @gil9red https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/dc2f48238440f5e98f9a80814bdf6865

Comment: Грязные руки прочь от чистых лямбд :)